Chrome blocks file download after some time on page
I'm working on React app that gets some urls from server in format
{
        filename: 'filename',
        url: 'url',
      },

and then renders buttons in very common way
       <button onClick={() => downloadFile(file.url, file.filename)}>{file.filename}</button>
where downloadFile is a simple function
export const downloadFile = (url: string, filename: string) => {
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = `${url}?download`;
  link.download = `${filename}`;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
};


So normally when user clicks on button, browser starts downloading file.
Problem is when you spend about 5 minutest on page without refreshing, and then click on button, Chrome shows error: "Check internet connection"
Error Image
After refreshing page/url change everything works fine again
And the problem is not appearing in Mozila
